# what about JavaScript in android?

Tags: javascript, android

I am a android developer. I want to develop an android app but want to code in javascript for that. Is it possible using ReactNative?

http://www.reactnative.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can defiantly write phone apps in JS, there are quite few options on the market:

On one hand there are hybrid apps, which written in HTML, CSS, JS and are built usually by something like cordova in order to communicate with phone API's. Some good frameworks that help you with the build and styling proccess are: Phonegap and Ionic.

And you have the react-native approach which basicly compiles the JS code to native phone components.

Both approaches let you reuse parts of your code in multiple platforms(Android, IOS).

While in hybrid apps you can reuse almost all of your code but just build for each platform. On react native you will have to code your views for each platform while your BL will stay the same if you written the code properly.

Comment: Appcelerator / Titanium whatever it is called nowadays is a good solution too. Compiles to native iOS/Android and I think Windows Phone support nowadays too. Has it's share of problems but what doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use WebView for this. Then register the JavaScriptInterface on your webview. JavaScriptInterFace can be a inner class as shown below. This class will have a function that you can call from html page( via javaScript ) and inside this function you can write code to change activity.

```
public class JavascriptInterfaceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    WebView wv;

    JavaScriptInterface JSInterface;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // register class containing methods to be exposed to JavaScript

        JSInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
        wv.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface, "JSInterface"); 

        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myPage.html");

    }


    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void changeActivity()
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(JavascriptInterfaceActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the html page

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessage()
{
JSInterface.changeActivity();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And if you develop android app through HTML, JAVA SCRIPT then use phonegap.

Comment: Yes it is also possible to built android app through ReactNative. Go through with this url to start .. "http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html"

Answer (score 0):

Yes obviously you can use ReactNative to develop the android applications. You need to write the app code in javascript in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You must use react native in this case. It has native components exposed to javascript. If you need some special component(That is not available in GitHub), you can write that native module in Android and IOS respectively. Also, it has a great community support.